# GWT MVP Example

Tags: gwt, mvp

Does anyone know a good production scale open source project written with GWT and the MVP pattern.  I am flip flopping on a few approaches to design and wanted to see if I could find a project that tackled similar issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer comes a bit late, but I hope it can be useful. The largest example of a GWT application using MVP that I've found is [Apache hupa](http://james.apache.org/hupa/index.html). It uses [gwt-presenter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-presenter/).

Answer (score 1):

How about [gwt-mvp-sample](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mvp-sample/) ? :)